# Test Navigation Component with SafeArgs and Mockito

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso, android-architecture-navigation, ui-testing

I'm trying to test if a fragment A calls fragment B through Navigation Component's navigate(NavDirection) method, and using Mockito. The problem is that the action from fragment A to fragment B has safe args (one object, to be exact), and when trying to do the following:

```
verify(navController).navigate(FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentB(payload))
```

Mockito throws an "Argument(s) are different!" error, and the difference between the calls is the instance of `payload`. What I'm doing here is that the (mocked) viewmodel of this fragment A receives the intent extra of the activity that launched the fragment (with launchFragmentInHiltContainer helper method), and catches the payload object from it (this object is then used in the arguments of FragmentADirection's action method). This is the moment where the "other instance" is created, but I don't need Mockito to verify the equality of instances, instead I just need to check if fragment A called navigate to fragment B correctly.

Is there a way to achieve this using Mockito?

**Flow of code:**

1. Fragment A calls viewmodel, passing it's activity reference
2. viewmodel catches intent.extras with the payload
3. viewModel calls the navigate method passing the payload caught in the previous step

P.S.: I'm using Hilt, and I'm initializing my mock instance of navController this way:

```
private val navController = mock(NavController::class.java)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't following the [guide to testing Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-testing) which specifically uses the [`TestNavHostController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/testing/TestNavHostController) and **not** mocks?

Comment: I was using it before, but for some reason the test becomes very flaky, as it takes sometimes too long to complete, then it fails (I check for the current destination's id), but sometimes it passes. Reading the documentation it says that it's recommended to use Mockito, that's why I switched to it then

Comment: Uh no. Mockito is only recommended if you are using an ancient version of Navigation that doesn't have a verifiable test fake that synchronously update it state immediately when you call navigate, there's no possibility of flaking when it comes to using `TestNavHostController` - you have something else wrong with your test setup, but you haven't include your test here, so we can't help you with that.

Comment: Hm. I'm going to have a look again on `TestNavHostController`, if I solve my problem I will write an answer here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I did not find a way to make Mockito check the difference between payload data instead of instance, I tried again using `TestNavHostController` as @ianhanniballake suggested, and while I was refactoring the code I noticed that when I was checking for a text in a view, instead of using `R.string` I was using `R.id`, which caused the test to fail. Now that I have corrected that, everything seems to be working just fine.

So, for this situation, check if you are doing some wrong assertion before looking into `navController.currentDestination?.id` value.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).